# How to convert mssql function to mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

I have `MSSQLserver DB` which i am going to migrate to `MYSQL`. I have converted almost all `stored procedures` but i am not able to `convert mssql user defined function`  to `mysql function`.

**MSSQL Fuction:**

```
create Function [dbo].[CsvSplit] ( @Array varchar(max),@separator varchar(5)) 
returns @IntTable table 
    (RValue nvarchar(400))
AS
begin

--  declare @separator char(1)
--  set @separator = ','

    declare @separator_position int 
    declare @array_value varchar(1000) 

    set @array = @array + @separator

    while patindex('%'+@separator+'%' , @array) <> 0 
    begin

      select @separator_position =  patindex('%'+@separator+'%' , @array)
      select @array_value = left(@array, @separator_position - 1)
    if len(@array_value)>0 
        Insert @IntTable
        Values (@array_value )

      select @array = stuff(@array, 1, @separator_position, '')
    end

    return
end
```

**Usage:**

```
SELECT TOP 1 lower(RValue) FROM CsvSplit('s,d,b',',')
```

**Please can any one help me to convert this same function with same parameter to mysql??**

Comment: You can not just convert the code to MySQL that simple. [Check out this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20108439/9290012)

Comment: Even TOP is not a mysql command

Comment: I know that mysql has 'limit' similar to sqlserver 'top'.

please read the post before commenting @P.Salmon i have already mentioned i have sqlserver version and i want to convert to mysql.

Comment: An exact conversion is not possible, as MySQL does not support to return a resultset from a function (so you cannot use `select * from function()`, but you could use a proc that inserts into a temp table and then select from it). For ways to split your string in MySQL, check [Can you split/explode a field in a MySQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/471914/6248528), if you e.g. always just need a single n'th value, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43156526/6248528), if you need a table, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32586238/6248528) (you can insert it into a temptable)