# Import database SQL on phpMyAdmin

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin

How do I import a Database backup in SQL Sever on phpMyAdmin.
I tried backing up an .sql file of SQL Server and importing this file into phpMyAdmin.
But I get an Syntax error.
Someone help me.

[image]

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'U' at line 1

Someone help me. Thanks.

Comment: Clearly you have a syntax error in your sql file. From what kind of database did you create the SQL backup file? Because if it's something else then MySQL or MariaDB syntax errors could occur.

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin is an interface for connecting to a MySQL or MariaDB database server. You may already know, but SQL (which stands for Structured Query Language) is the programming language or file format used to import and export data (or table structure) to and from a database server. The problem, as you've discovered, is that SQL Server and MySQL/MariaDB don't speak the same flavor of SQL. So while they both can import and export to `.sql` files, they aren't directly compatible.

One possible workaround is to select MSSQL from the "SQL compatibility mode" dropdown on the phpMyAdmin import page. This make an effort to translate the MSSQL commands in to their equivalent MySQL/MariaDB statements. Sometimes this is easy; for instance the DELETE syntax is different but rather straightforward to change, other times there are deep differences in the data types used and the import may still fail. Still, I'd start with changing the import mode and seeing if you continue to see errors; you may then be able to manually fix any problems that arise.

Related: [How to convert mssql script to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108380/how-to-convert-mssql-script-to-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

There are two method :

1. use ODBC open database to convert your database from sql server then one by one import the database in phpmyadmin after enabling odbc extension in xampp.

2.(Complex method) use csv file for exporting sql and then import to PHPmyadmin .